# How do I view my ink tank levels

Tags: printing

I have a canon iP3600 printer and was unable to print a test page out.  Though the driver is OK I think that one of the ink tanks may be empty, but with Linux I can not view the status of the printer such as the ink tank levels and the head alignment etcetera. how do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man/escputil.1.html) for that: escputil

> escputil is a command line utility to perform various maintenance tasks
>          on  Epson  Stylus inkjet printers.  These tasks include head alignment,
>          head cleaning, nozzle check, printer identification, and  retrieval  of
>          ink level from the printer.
>
> **-i, --ink-level**
>
> Obtain the ink level from the printer. This requires read/write access to the raw printer device.

You can find it in the Ubuntu software center or click the button below it...

[image]

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: escputil is for epson printer. What about canon inkjet printers?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ink](http://ink.sourceforge.net/) command line tool to show ink level of your printer.

Install it:

```
# apt install ink
```

And check your printer, eg:

```
$ ink -p bjnp
ink 0.5.2 (c) 2015 Markus Heinz

Canon MG3600 series

Black:                                  90%
Color:                                 100%
```